# Do values need to be initialised to function in for loops?

Tags: python, scope, variable-declaration

I'm learning c++ and our Prof. wants us to understand whether the things we have learnt would/wouldn't function in other languages.

Would the following code in python print 
"I love my dog ..." (for every array instance)
AND
"my favourite dog is jack" 
or just the latter?

```
pets = ['flufffy', "jack", 'larry']
for a in pets:
    print "I love my dog %s" % a
print "My favourite dog is %s" % pets[1]
```

in c++ if the `a` was not declared the loop wouldn't compile/run properly if mi correct.

Comment: Did you try executing it and see what happens?

Comment: Well at the moment it will error because `fruit` isn't defined. Is there more to this code?

Comment: What is `f`? it does not appear in the code

Comment: Also, your final line uses `&` in two places where you almost certainly meant `%`.

Comment: im unfamiliar with how to execute python code @Derlin

Comment: What do you mean by "initialized"? I [converted your code to C++](https://ideone.com/H2DSf8) and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, assignment includes implicit declaration (it's just that declaration only means "the name exists", and doesn't force a static type).

```
for a in pets:
```

works just fine (so all the lines you expect are printed, the loop isn't skipped for whatever reason you seem to expect), because the `for` loop assigns to `a`, implicitly declaring it. It's not like C++ where there would need to be a declaration like `std::string a` (either before or in the loop) or `auto a` (in the loop) to declare that `a` exists with a known type.

To be clear, C++ would only require `a` to be *declared* (and it could be done in the loop itself, e.g. `for (const auto& a : pets) {`), not specifically *initialized*, to make the loop work.